# post запросы в slim framework

Tags: php, mysql, post, slim

Скажите, безопасно ли использовать такую конструкцию:

```
$app->post("/login", function () use ($app) {
$email = $app->request()->post('email');
$password = md5($app->request()->post('password'));
$rows3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email` = '$email' AND `Password` = '$password' LIMIT 1");
```

---

Или $email и $password стоит обрабатывать еще с htmlspecialchars и mysql_real_escape_string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не безопасно. Метод post() возвращает сырые данные.

По возможности перейдите с использования устаревшего расширения mysql на PDO, mysqli, или какой-нибудь ORM - там можно использовать параметризированные запросы, а в случае их использования можно не задумыватся об экскейпинге строк(оно в этом случае просто не нужно).

Ну а htmlspecialchars при помещении данных в базу обычно не используют - его используют только при выводе данных из базы на страницу